# Protege - DL Query and subclasses

Tags: owl, protege, protege4, dlquery

I'm using protege to test OWL Ontologies for my program.
Is there a way to ask in the DL Query tab if an entity is a subclass of another entity?
The autocomplete tab does not suggest the keyword *subclass*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of ASK queries in the DL Query Tab. The idea is to write Class Expressions and then do inferences based on what you selected in the check box section.

Thus, to check if a class `A` is a subclass of a class `B`, the idea would be to use `A` and then compute the super classes and check if `B` is contained in the result.

See the [documentation](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/DLQueryTab)

An alternative query language would be SPARQL.

Answer (score 0):

**Protégé 5.5. :**

In the DL query window :

- enter the entity name

In the "Query for"

- check "Subclasses"

Press execute